# how to write spring jpa specification on inner join

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

i have group by query as below , how would i create spring jpa specification based on below query..

```sql
select a.* from credit_transaction a 
inner join (select vh_owner_id, max(created_dttm) as created_dttm from credit_transaction group by vh_owner_id) as b on  a.vh_owner_id = b.vh_owner_id and a.created_dttm = b.created_dttm
```

I can write plain join with the below code.. but how would I achieve jpa spec with group by on the above query.

```
return (root, query, cb) -> {
    Join<CreditTransaction, VehicleOwner> creditTransVhOwnerJoin = root.join(joinMO.getTableName(),
        joinMO.getJoinType());
    query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(orderBy)));
    return cb.like(cb.lower(creditTransVhOwnerJoin.get(joinMO.getKey()).as(String.class)),
        "%" + joinMO.getValue().toLowerCase() + "%");
};
```